# Jailbroken iOS 8.4 iPhone 4S device is now disabled and requires to connect to iTunes

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

I broke my iPhone 4S touch "screen and glass last year and left it unused because i bought iPhone 5 .. anyway.. recently I decided to fix it. I bought new touchscreen&glass and it works. However I entered few invalid passcodes and now my iPhone 4S says "iPhone is disabled. Connect to iTunes". Its running on iOS 8.4 jailbroken and if I restore it to 9.3.5 i wont be able to use it anymore ... as there is no jailbrake for it. I even believe I may remember my passcode if i had the oprion to enter it few more times .... so what I can do guys to be able to use it once again? Is there any way to try at least one more passcode that I believe should be the correct one or what basically i can so now ?

Answer (score 1):

[Per Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204306):

> If you enter the wrong passcode in to an iOS device six times in a row, you'll be locked out and a message will say that your device is disabled.
>
> Unless you made a backup before you forgot your passcode, there isn't a way to save your device's data. You'll need to erase your device, which deletes all of your data and settings.